# What makes a space 'locally Euclidean' Euclidean?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, manifolds

I come from a Physics background so I realise if my knowledge is lacking in this. I'm following an introduction to manifolds and to start, I found this definition of a 'locally Euclidean' topological space from Wikipedia:

> A topological space $X$ is called locally Euclidean if there is a non-negative integer $n$ such that every point in $X$ has a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to real n-space $\mathbb{R}^n$

What defines whether a space is 'Euclidean'? To me, I would associate a Euclidean space as a space where we can define a length element $ds^2$ as the sum of the squares of cartesian coordinates eg. $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2+...$. This doesn't seem to fit in this context because no where in the definition of a manifold include a notion of distance. Also, I don't see how having a homeomorphism relates to this notion of distance.

So why does the existence of a homeomorphism have anything to do with being Euclidean?

Comment: Although the answers below are correct, it is worth noting that the terminology is entirely anachronistic. Euclid did geometry axiomatically – the mere notion of "coordinates" and "$\mathbb R^n$" did not exist until hundreds of years later.

Comment: As said below, this is largely a terminological matter. However, if you care about the "locally Euclidean-ness" of a manifold allowing for locally defined metric features, when your locally Euclidean space is second-countable and Hausdorff, then you *can* define a metric on it which does what you expect it to.

Comment: If it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ it's Euclidean. What makes it local for a manifold is that it's at a point. Like a circle is not Euclidean but it has a well-defined tangent line everywhere so it's locally Euclidean.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: the concept of "tangent line" is not topological. Any polygon is locally Euclidean.

Comment: Do you know what the words "topological space" mean in this definition and how they relate to the word "space" that you are casually using in your question? If not, you should try to sort this out before trying to resolve the issue with the meaning of the word "Euclidean."

Comment: @RobArthan it's not necessary to have a tangent space everywhere but it's sufficient.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: sufficient for what? The question is about a condition on topological spaces.

Comment: @Joe: I think that in this case, the term "Euclidean" is not anachronistic in its use by pure mathematicians to identify the present day generalisations of the kind of spaces the ancient Greeks were interested in (what we now call $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3\$).  Coordinates and all that were begun by Descartes. In this topological context, "Euclidean" is just right.

Comment: @RobArthan It's sufficient to show that a circle is locally Euclidean, just like I said in the first place. I don't know how you've gotten confused.

Comment: I'm not in the slightest confused. From a topological view-point, the notion of  "tangent line" has no meaning and is irrelevant to the easy proof that $S^1$ is locally Euclidean using polar coordinates.

Comment: “What makes a space 'locally Euclidean' Euclidean?” is not a grammatical sentence. Are you asking about “locally Euclidean” spaces or “Euclidean” spaces? And what is it that you are asking? (And why am I the first to ask such questions?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really valid complaint about overuse of an adjective. Like most people, you probably first encountered the word "Euclidean" in the context of geometry, where probably you studied Euclid's fifth postulate and how it characterizes "flat space," and we could have negative or positively curved space without it.

In this case, we are only speaking of topology. For example, the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is *the same* as that of the hyperbolic plane (they are homeomorphic, the homeomorphism just doesn't preserve distance). So when we say a topological space is locally (or globally) Euclidean, we just means it looks like Euclidean space topologically.

Answer (score 2):

"The" *Euclidean space* of dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is, by definition, $\mathbb{R}^n$, endowed with the topology induced by the usual Euclidean metric, i.e.
$$ d(x,y) = \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^{n} |x_j-y_j|^2 }, $$
as well as the standard vector space structure over $\mathbb{R}$.
Note that a Euclidean space carries a *lot* more structure than just the topological structure (it has a metric, there is a vector space structure running around, there is an inner product (which actually induces a norm from which the metric can be recovered), etc).

Note that, while this has historical links to the geometry of Euclid, the modern definition is largely unrelated, and has been abstracted away from classical Greek geometry—the modern notion of "the Euclidean space" typically involves all of the structure described above (especially the metric and inner product, which can be used to measure distance and angle, but also the other structures).  On the other hand, "a Euclidean space" may refer to any space which has some specific number of these features, and "a locally Euclidean space" only has the (local) topological properties described.

When talking about a locally Euclidean space, as defined in the question, most of this structure is forgotten.  *Only* the topological structure matters.  So a space if locally Euclidean if each point has some neighborhood which is *topologically* equivalent to some Euclidean space.  The topology on that original space needn't come from a metric, and that space needn't have any deeper structure—we only care about the topology at this level.

Answer (score 1):

The topological space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and any space homeomorphic to it) is also called ''Euclidean $n$-space'' and a bunch of other things containing the adjective ''Euclidean''.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics the term "Euclidean space" typically refers to $\Bbb{R}^n$ together with its standard topological, metric and algebraic structure.

You've correctly noticed that term "locally Euclidean" does not involve metric at all, and as such is a purely topological term. This leads to the definition of "[topological manifold](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold)". But if we want more structure on it, e.g. if we want to do calculus on a manifold (which os often desired) then this is not enough. And you have to introduce the notion of being differentiable, which deep down already is closely related to the particular choice of metric and algebraic structure on $\Bbb{R}^n$.